# Cufon text overlays Fancybox

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox, cufon

I'm using the Cufon library to display some text on [this page](http://bit.ly/9omTGq).

If you look (via Firefox 3.6.x) at the section called "Thank You Gifts" and click the text in that area, you'll see a Fancybox (ver. 1.3.1) pop up. When it pops up, I have to hide the Cufon text title of the section or it will overlay the Fancybox. How do I fix this so I don't have to hide/show the title and have the Fancybox on top of it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fancybox div (`#fancybox_wrap`) has a z-index of 1101 while you cufon (in `css/cms.css`) has a z-index of 100000.

You should make the z-index of `#fancybox-wrap` in `global/js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.css` higher then 100000, don't forget the overlay (`#fancybox-overlay` which has an z-index of 1100).

Comment: Thanks, Tim. Let me test that :)

Comment: That was it! I had a CSS class called embed-section-title that wrapped around the Cufon text, and its z-index was 100000. Once I set that to 1, things started working. Thanks, Tim.